# Create an ArrayList on a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have a problem creating a list on a Servlet. I have the following code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    List lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
    String ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //elegimos a qué pantalla pasar en función de la acción que nos llegue de la interfaz

    if ("Buscar todas las recetas".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getAllReceipes());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
              lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
              request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getSomeReceipes(lIngredients));
              request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
             lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
    }
    }
```

Te problem is that all the time I save the same value. I don´t know if its possible to reset the "ingrediente" and "action" strings that I´ve made and let the user select an other value from the JSP.

Thanks.

This is the JSP:

```
`<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./optionServlet" method="POST">     
    <table border="1">
        <form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on">     
        <th><FONT FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Ingredientes: </th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Ingredientes" value="${Receta.Ingredientes}" list="datalist1" /></td>
        <datalist id="datalist1">
             <option value="Aceite"><option value="AceiteOliva"> <option value="AceitunasNegras"><option value="Ajo"><option value="Albahaca">
             <option value="AlbahacaFresca"><option value="Azucar"><option value="CarnePicada"><option value="Cebolla"><option value="CebollaMorada">
             <option value="Croutons"><option value="DienteDeAjo"><option value="Espinaca"><option value="FileteSalmon"><option value="Guisantes">
             <option value="Harina"><option value="Huevo"><option value="LaminaParaCanelones"><option value="Lechuga"><option value="Macarrones">
             <option value="Mantequilla"><option value="MasaPizza"><option value="Miel"><option value="Mostaza"><option value="Oregano">
             <option value="PanRallado"><option value="Patata"><option value="PechugaPollo"><option value="Pepino"><option value="Perejil"><option value="Pimienta">
             <option value="PimientoRojo"><option value="QuesoFeta"><option value="QuesoMozzarella"><option value="QuesoParmesano"><option value="QuesoRicota">
             <option value="Sal"><option value="SalsaQueso"><option value="Tomate"><option value="TomateTriturado"><option value="Zanahoria">
        </datalist>
        <button><input type="submit" name="action" value="Buscar todas las recetas" /></button>
        <button><input type="submit" name="action" value="Buscar por ingredientes" /></button>
        <button><input type="submit" name="action" value="Agregar ingrediente" /></button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <font color="#74DF00"><b><c:out value="${mensajesOK}"/></b></font> </td>`
```

This is the correct code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    List lIngredients = (List) session.getAttribute("Ingredientes");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    if (lIngredients == null) {
       lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
       session.setAttribute("Ingredientes", lIngredients);
    }
    String ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //elegimos a qué pantalla pasar en función de la acción que nos llegue de la interfaz

    if ("Buscar todas las recetas".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getAllReceipes());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
              lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
              request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getSomeReceipes(lIngredients));
              request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
             lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
             request.getRequestDispatcher("option.jsp").forward(request, response);
             ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
             action = request.getParameter("action");
    }
}
```

Comment: "All the time I save the same value" - Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I have a jsp page where I have a list of ingredients. I would like to choose a different one all the time, instead of that once I have some information on the "ingrediente" parameter, I cant choose a new one, thats why all the time I save the same ingredient that I wrote on the first time

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the foreign (spanish?) texts, but could it be you meant `while("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action))` (no `!`)?

Comment: Ingredientes: Ingredient  ;  Buscar todas las recetas: look for all the receipes   ;  Buscar por ingredientes: look for ingredient  ; Agregar ingrediente: add ingredient. while the user didn´t press that button then it should keep asking. I thought about clear the information of the button and the inredient maybe? (sorry for the spanish!)

Comment: Why are you looping? If the action comes as "Agregar ingrediente", the loop will become indefinite.

Comment: That´s what Im saying. If I can reset the value of the button, then the user on some point will press an other button, so the value will be different and the loop will end.

Comment: Are you receiving multiple ingredients or one at a time? How's the user providing the value? Using `<select>`?

Comment: I have an interface with a list of ingredients and three buttons: add an other ingredient, look for a recipe, look for all recipes. So I would like to choose one ingredient, press the button "add other ingredient" and add it to the list, choose an other press the same button and add it to the list. Until I press the "look for a recipe" button

Comment: Are you displaying the list of selected ingredients too? If yes, does the selected ingredients list change but remains with only one ingredient (i.e. loses the last selected ingredient) or the list never changes and has just the same single value all the time? It would help if you could post your JSP code as well? Never mind the Spanish, puedo leer un poco español.

Comment: Its a static list, so the list never changes, it always has the same value. Thanks for your help and for your spanish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a new `List` at every request.

```
List lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Since, it's a local variable it ceases to exist as soon as that request completes. So, that the previous values are available to you when the user finally decides to search for the recipes, you need to persist the ingredient `List` into a session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List lIngredients = (List) session.getAttribute("Ingredientes");

if (lIngredients == null) {
    List lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
    session.setAttribute("Ingredientes", lIngredientes);
}
```

Comment: Please note that you''ll need to put the list in the `session` too. Otherwise, `session.getAttribute()` will return `null` always. I missed that and have updated that in my answer now.